# Select List Rendering when it should not be

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a VF page that select multiple records from child (Contingency__c) and add them to parent (Billing_Change_Form__c) related list. Everything work fine other than one issue. Upon selecting a checkbox, the list renders itself with the same records. Here are the screen shots:
Without Clicking:
[image]

When I select a record it show this:
[image]

They are the same records but added 2 more times.

My visualforce code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="Fasle" standardController="Billing_Change_Form__c" extensions="test2">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:PageBlock id="counter">

                    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                      <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!mySave}" onComplete="window.top.close();"/>   
                      <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.top.close();" immediate="true" action="{!closePopup}"/>  
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!show}" var="e" title="show">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.check}"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!inIt}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column value="{!e.con.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!e.con.discovery_amount__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!e.con.billing_begins_date__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!e.con.report_description__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!e.con.contingency__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>



        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Extension:

```
public class test2 {
    public string lookup{get;set;}
    public list<conCase> caseList{get;set;}
    public boolean allbool{get;set;}
    public string inputValue{get;set;}
    public boolean bool{get;set;}
    public set<id> caseIds{get;set;}
    Billing_Change_form__c[] accID = [Select account__c from Billing_Change_Form__c where 
                                               id = :System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id')];
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public test2(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        controller = con;
        caseList = new list<conCase>();
        bool = false;
        caseIds = new Set<id>();
    }



    public void inIt(){
        List<Contingency__c> selectedCase = new list<Contingency__c>();
        lookUp = '';
        for(conCase conObj : caseList){
            if(conObj.check !=false){
                system.debug('conObj.con'+ conObj.con);
                selectedCase.add(conObj.con);
                lookUp += conObj.con.name + ', ';
                system.debug('lookup:'+ lookup);
                caseIds.add(conObj.con.id);
            }
    }
        bool = true;
    }

    public List<conCase> getShow(){
        for(Contingency__c coObj : [Select id, name,billing_type__c, report_description__c, discovery_amount__c,
                        billing_begins_date__c, contingency__c, VENDOR_INVOICE__r.Account_del__r.Id from Contingency__c
            where (VENDOR_INVOICE__r.Account_del__r.Id = :accID[0].Account__c) ])
                                    {
            caseList.add(new conCase(coObj, allBool));
        }
        return caseList;
    }

    public PageReference mySave(){
        list<Contingency__c> updateSelectedCase = new list<Contingency__c>();
        id billId = ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        System.debug('Bill ID is' + billID);
        for(Contingency__c co:[select id, name, bill_form__c from Contingency__c where id = :caseIds ]){
            co.bill_form__c = billId;
            updateSelectedCase.add(co);
        }
        update updateSelectedCase;
        return null;

       /* PageReference billPage =  ApexPages.currentPage();
        billPage.setRedirect(true);
        return billPage;*/
    }

    public void closePopup(){
        bool = false;
    }
    public void add(){
        bool = true;
    }
       public class conCase{
        public contingency__c con{get;set;}
        public boolean check{get;set;}
        public conCase(contingency__c c, boolean boo){
            con = c;
            check = boo;           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-initialize your list

```
public List < conCase > getShow() {
    caseList = new list <conCase> (); // this is the fix
        for (Contingency__c coObj: [Select id, name, billing_type__c, report_description__c, discovery_amount__c,
                billing_begins_date__c, contingency__c, VENDOR_INVOICE__r.Account_del__r.Id from Contingency__c
                where(VENDOR_INVOICE__r.Account_del__r.Id =: accID[0].Account__c)
            ]) {
            caseList.add(new conCase(coObj, allBool));
        }
    return caseList;
}
```

Comment: @Ajit Chakraborty Thank so much!! It worked!! ; however, now it is deselecting the checkbox that I select. So when I check the box, it renders and deselect the box that I checked.

Comment: You need to preserve that data between server communication using hidden variable

Comment: Any tips on how to do that? I am very new to development. this is my first class and page.